# Align two images vertically in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

I'm trying to align the arrow to the bird nest vertically such that they share the same center horizontal line. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: I am not a Word user, but are you able to turn each into a like-size cell, with the content vertically centred, and then have the bird's nest in the left cell, with the arrow in the right cell? Obviously this will also depend very much on the white space in each image, and you might also have to rotate the arrow before entering it into a table.

Comment: No problem, - bearing in mind the 'fun' I had with Word before I defected to OpenOffice Writer, I am pleased and absolutely amazed... =] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One advantage of using the following approach instead of a table is that the images can overlap.

Click one image, and then hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while you click the other. Then, on the **Picture Tools** > **Format** tab, in the **Arrange** group, click **Align** > **Align Middle**.

I believe that the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click approach to multi-selection works only if the **Position** setting of both images is something other than **In Line with Text**. At any rate, you may sometimes find that you just can't select both images as described above. In that case, check the **Position** settings. Alternatively, insert a drawing canvas on the page (on the **Insert** tab, in the **Illustrations** group, click **Shapes** > **New Drawing Canvas**) and then insert your images onto the canvas. You should then be able to select both images and click **Align** > **Align Middle**.

(Here, inserting a drawing canvas amounts to the more or less the same thing as changing the **Position** settings, because the objects on a drawing canvas aren't positioned in line with text.)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't able to select two images at once for some reason but the drawing canvas method worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a table and centering the contents. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Comments are often deleted.  Please make this a better answer by explaining the procedure in sufficient detail that somebody who isn’t already familiar with the concept will be able to understand it and implement it. … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.